# 3 legged authentication for react-native app of bim360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there a way that we can use 3-legged authentication on an app built in react-native. 
The problem here is how do you add a callback in our app where there is no route.

Answer (score 0):

This 3-legged authentication with react-native tutorial can help:

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-react-native-au-talk

It shows you how to build a React Native app that logs into BIM360 using 3-legged authentication.

It explains how the callback works differently for mobile (requiring a proxy server to handle session handoff)

Let me know if you want more details on this mechanism.

Cheers
Michael
[image]